# Sharing username and password to the next HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to share the username and password information to the right next HTML page after succeeding the login. Because the items in the second HTML page will appear according to the user identity and privilege.

I tried sharing the same js file between the 2 HTML pages. The first set the variables and the second get them, but they don't get passed. How do I do it? javascript? jquery? on the server side??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should always do this on server side. After confirming login at the server side create a user session variable. It persists on the server when request comes again from the same browser/ client. Read about session variables.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in many ways, but as the first language you mentioned is javascript, I will show you in it. So saving data across pages there are variable called session variable and the process of saving/retrieving them is called session management. There are many ways for session management, one most common way is using cookie. You can save the values in cookie, like this:

```
setCookie("key", "value", expire_time(integer));
```

And now on next page to get this value you can use:

```
var val = getCookie("key");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Username and password is a sensitive information you have to share it form Server side in these ways:

1. Use post method to share this information.
2. Set session on first page For user type and retrieve on very next page.

As your question says second page will appear according to the user identity and privilege. You can set user identity (User Type) and its privileges.